# Working with recurrence

Tags: induction

$$
\DeclareMathOperator{ceil}{ceil}
T(n) =
\begin{cases}
10 & \text{ if } n=1 \\
7 \, T(\ceil(n/2)) + n^2 & \text{ if } n>1
\end{cases}
$$
   a) Use n to find positive real constants c,d such
      that T(n) <= c n^{lg base 2 7} - d n^2, for all n that are powers of 2

I'm having trouble understanding when to use my Induction Hypothesis:
BC: 10 <= c
IS: let n>= 1 
    Suppose f(n)<= c n^{lg base 2 7} - d n^2 
f(n+1) = 7 T(ceil(n/2)) + n^2
<= 7 T(n+1) + n^2 
which is where i want to use the IH, but it makes no sense to use the IH on f(n+1) because it defeats the purpose, however i dont know how else to deal with the ceil

Comment: What does 'ceil' mean ?

Comment: ceiling, as in round up, ceil(1.5) = 2

Comment: Ok, thanks. You seem to have an issue with your expression of f(n+1). Moreover, since you have to prove the formula for n powers of 2, you should not build $T(n+1)$ but $T(2n)$ in your IS...

Comment: Otherwise, the exercise seems a bit weird to me since ceil(n/2)=n/2 for all n powers of 2 but n=1.

Comment: we were instructed to use n, rather than 2n, and yea the exception of n=1 is a pain

Comment: Are you allowed to write $n=2^k$ and use an induction argument on $k$? And what exactly stop you from writing $T(n)=7T(n/2)+n^2$ if $n>1$ ?

Comment: i just tried using this with complete induction, i get to f(n) = 7c(n/2)^log2_7 - d(n/2)^2 +n^2, however im having trouble connecting it to be <= cn^log2_7 - dn^2

Comment: Did you mean $T(n) \le c\;n^{log_2 7} + d\;n^2$ instead of $T(n) \le c\;n^{log_2 7} - d\;n^2$?